# Raise an exception

Tags: exception, go

I would want to raise an exception as it's made in Python or Java --to finish the program with an error message--.

An error message could be returned to a parent function:

```
func readFile(filename string) (content string, err os.Error) {
    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return "", os.ErrorString("read " + filename + ": " + err)
    }
    return string(content), nil
}
```

but I want that it can be finished when the error is found. Would be correct the next one?

```
func readFile(filename string) (content string) {
    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)

    defer func() {
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    return string(content)
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By convention, Go doesn't do things like this. It has [`panic` and `recover`](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Handling_panics), which are sort of exception-like, but they're only used in really exceptional circumstances. Not finding a file or similar is not an exceptional circumstance at all, but a very regular one. Exceptional circumstances are things like dereferencing a `nil` pointer or dividing by zero.

Comment: That depends on the level of the application. For quick and dirty scripts, prototypes, etc., it may very well be an unrecoverable error; not because it can't be done, but because it's not worth the effort to write those three lines.

Comment: Fair enough. Just don't do this kind of thing in a released package or application and expect me to use it. :)

Comment: To old  by now, but how about stop the app if the .env file is missing some required keys?